# PreparedStatement - syntax error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a problem with PreparedStatement.

This is my function that adds new user to MySQL database:

```
public static void createUser(String fn, String sn, String log, String pass, int accNum, String qst, String answ) {
        try {
            Connection conn = (Connection) mySQLConnector.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(
                      "INSERT INTO users"
                      + "(FirstName, LastName, Login, Password, AccountNumber, Ballance, Question, Answer)"
                      + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
            ps.setString(1, fn);
            ps.setString(2, sn);
            ps.setString(3, log);
            ps.setString(4, pass);
            ps.setInt(5, accNum);
            ps.setDouble(6, 0);
            ps.setString(7, qst);
            ps.setString(8, answ);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is an error that I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I have no idea what is wrong with my query. ColumnNames are ok, function arguments are also ok.

I've tried adding '' to columns names (like that: 'FirstName') but i t still doesn't work...

**EDIT:**

Adding spaces did not helped.I even made it in one line:

> "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Login, Password,
>   AccountNumber, Ballance, Question, Answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)"

and still gives the same error

Comment: Are you sure the column name is `Ballance` (misspelled with two "l"s)?

Comment: Usually it helps to debug the code, put a breakpoint after prepared statement is created. Then you can copy/paste the query in a query editor to figure out what's wrong. Right now, I can see that you are missing whitespace and paranthesis in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Unrelated to the error: Why are you casting the `PreparedStatement`? There is no need for that (I assume you are casting to the MySQL implementation class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing spaces. Change your SQL to :

```
"INSERT INTO users " // space added
 + "(FirstName, LastName, Login, Password, AccountNumber, Ballance, Question, Answer) " // space added
 + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

EDIT : I missed the missing closing bracket at the end of the VALUES clause.

Comment: Still not working. I even made it in one line: "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Login, Password, AccountNumber, Ballance, Question, Answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" and still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add spaces and bracket

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(
                      "INSERT INTO users "
                      + "(FirstName, LastName, Login, Password, AccountNumber, Ballance, Question, Answer) "
                      + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix this:

```
 "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

to this:

```
 "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```